# How can i get a list of the extended html colors in .NET?

Tags: .net

I would love to get a list of the extended html colors, like the ones displayed [here](http://www.scriptingmaster.com/html/html-extended-color-names.asp)

I need both the Color Name and the Html value.
Is there any available function in .net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var colors = 
  Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)).Cast<KnownColor>()
    .Select(k => Color.FromKnownColor(k))
    .Where(k => !k.IsSystemColor)
```

And if you need hex and name just append:

```
.Select (k => new 
      { 
         Name = k.Name, 
         Hex = "#" + k.R.ToString("X2") + 
                     k.G.ToString("X2") + 
                     k.B.ToString("X2") 
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

[System.Drawing.Color](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is used for colors (including HTML colors) in .NET. The type has all the [CSS3 colors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-color/) as its static properties so they can be retrieved with reflection. `KnownColors` includes the list, too, but it also has unrelated colors.

```
typeof(Color).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Static|BindingFlags.Public)
/*.Where(p=>p.PropertyType == typeof(Color)) */       /* a possible extra precaution:
   * currently, they are all Color.
   * My way is to let the code break on casting instead if anything changes
   * to draw attention to the change.
   * You may also validate the total number against the spec (141)
   * (the table in the spec actually has 148 entries 'cuz it has both
   * "gray" and "grey" spellings). */
.Select(p=>(Color)(p.GetValue(null,null)))
```

Note that the list includes `Color.Transparent` which you may or may not want - since it's a valid CSS color, too.

Comment: Hello, how can i convert this to get the Hex value instead of the RGB?

Comment: @OrElse dunno what's a "hex" value that's not "#rrggbb". For the latter, Magnus already gave the code.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way to do it, the shortest and easiest I have found:

```
foreach (Color col in new ColorConverter().GetStandardValues())
{
    if (!col.IsSystemColor)
        Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", col.Name, ColorTranslator.ToHtml(Color.FromArgb(col.ToArgb())));
}
```

Another way to get the html code:

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} #{1}", col.Name, Color.FromArgb(col.ToArgb()).Name.Substring(2).ToUpper());
```

*Credits to these answers:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3821216/2321042 and
https://stackoverflow.com/a/28777828/2321042*